# Ngx-Editor in Microsoft Edge Not Saving Formatting

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, ngx-editor

Hey I'm trying to use the ngx-editor WYSIWYG editor in Microsoft Edge, but it doesn't store the formatting HTML content. It only saves text from the field. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox. For example, bold text in Chrome saves as `<b>Text\</b>` while in Edge it's just saved as `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test and able to produce the issue with MS Edge.

[image]

I also find that issue was also created on GitHub by you.

[Ngx-Editor Internet explorer and Edge issue on not getting formatted data](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/1856)

But we cannot correct this issue from Edge browser and Ngx Editor is not a product of Microsoft. So it is better you raise the issue on Ngx editor support forum.

Only they can correct this issue for their editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following,

```
const dom = document.getElementsByClassName('ngx-editor-textarea');
const txt = (dom && dom[0]) ? dom[0].innerHTML : '';
```